# How to sort a class which implemented Iterable<V> in Java?

Tags: java

The class I want to sort has implemented the interface `Iterable<V>`.

I am asking this since the mostly commonly used `Collection.sort()` fails to work here.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 3):

I believe that you are confusing about `Iterable`and `Comparable`. The goal is completely different. You can check the goal of each interface on java api.

Anyway, if you wanna to order/sort your elements in list using `Collections.sort`, you must to use the method that receive also a Comparator.

Use [Collections.sort(List, Comparator)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-java.util.Comparator-) instead of [Collections.sort(List)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-).

How to user `Comparator` you can check in [Comparator API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html).

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
public class SomeIterable<V extends Comparable<V>> implements Iterable<V> {
    @Override public Iterator<V> iterator() { ..... }
}
```

and

```
    Iterable<String> iterable = new SomeIterable<String>();
    // ...
    List<String> sorted = StreamSupport.stream(iterable.spliterator(), false)
        .sorted()
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

To sort a collection of objects you need them to be Comparable not Iterable. Implement Comparable with the comparison logic or create a dedicated Comparator.